# Qt serialization. QDataStream & operator<< for base class QPolygonF

Tags: c++, qt, operator-overloading

Having MyClass : QPolygonF I would like to create

```
void bin_write(QDataStream & out ) const
{
   out << (BASE CLASS QPOLYGONF)*this  ??
}
```

which calls the overload operator

```
QDataStream& operator<< ( QDataStream & stream, const QPolygonF & polygon )
```

I dont know how to tell it to call that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do:

```
out << *this;
```

There's no need for an explicit upcast here (as is generally the case) unless your subclass is also defining its own overload of `operator<<` (insertion operator) with `QDataStream`.

If your class does provide overloaded `operator<<` and you need to use QPolygonF's insertion operator (for example, in order to help implement operator<< for your subclass), then you can do:

```
out << static_cast<const QPolygonF&>(*this);
```

Comment: Any different in (QPolygonF) *this and what you mention with static_cast?

Comment: I think i figured out my mistake, QPolygon& and QPolygon. Forgot to pass it as a reference

Comment: @s093294 the static_cast is a lot safer since, say you changed your mind and made it so your class doesn't inherit QPolygonF anymore (example: QPolygon instead or your own polygon type). That cast would then fail and cause a compiler error, whereas the C-style cast would succeed and invoke undefined behavior (probably a confusing crash). Also yes, you want to work with references here instead of pointers unless your goal is to output pointer addresses rather than polygon data which I'm assuming is not what you are after.

Comment: Thank you. One follow up, theres also a cast i can use to cast a void* to a type myType* if the cast is not possible the casted value becomes 0 right? is it dynamic cast? Is it a bad approach to use that if my void* can be of 3 different types and just cast and check. The other solution would be to make a base class that all tree types could inheried but i dont find that fitting in my case.

Comment: void* to some_type* is, by nature, unsafe, but a static_cast does the trick. dynamic_cast is primarily for downcasting from base* to derived* safely (it'll actually throw an exception, std::bad_cast, if derived* doesn't inherit from base*).

Comment: In other words, void* to arbitrary_type* will always succeed since it can't possibly fail (neither the compiler or the runtime data associated with void* can tell us what it is or know what's associated at that memory address). With something like base* and RTTI enabled, dynamic_cast can look at the type information associated with the object and see whether that cast is valid. QT also has its own casting mechanism called qobject_cast which is a specialized dynamic_cast just for subclasses of QObject.

Comment: Thank you. Think i need one last question to understand the hole cast thing. I have class child : public parent  before i did (parent*)_mychild. I tried to change this to static_cast<parent*>(_mychild) but gets error "cannot convert from...."  So if dynamic cast can downcast, how about "upcast" ?